# Can I move the Google Drive folder to a different volume?

Tags: macos, google-apps

Is there a way to put the Google Drive folder on a different volume on my Mac (where I have more free space)?  I tried Googling the question, and just got tips about doing it on Windows.

Answer (score 33):

I figured it out.

1. Quit Google Drive and remove the Google Drive folder.
2. Restart Google Drive.
3. Error message saying that it can't find the folder will pop up.
4. Click the error message text to open a dialog in which one can specify a new folder.
5. Specify your new folder location.

Comment: Worked for me on El Capitan, and latest version of Google Drive. IMO this is better than disconnecting and re-installing/re-configuring, as it avoids re-downloading everything. Some files may need resyncing though, for me: out of 31K files only 94 needed resyncing.

Comment: works for mac mojave too :) nice tip

Answer (score 9):

Method 1:

1. Enter `Preferences`: menu bar -> Google Drive icon -> 3-dot icon
2. Choose `Disconnect account` in the Account tab. After you disconnect, your files will remain on your computer.
3. `Sign in` again by clicking the icon in the menu bar.
4. Step through until the last screen where you can setup up which folder to use.
5. Google Drive will download all/selected files to your computer.
6. You can delete your old files if you want.

Method 2:

1. `Quit` Google Drive from the menu bar icon.
2. `Move` the folder to your preferred new location, rename it if you want.
3. `Restart` Google Drive.
4. It will warn you that the folder is missing, select the new folder and Google drive will sync to that folder.

Comment: Method 1 worked well for me using "Backup and Sync by Google".

Answer (score 0):

You can move the drive folder to preferred location. Then quit the Google drive. The next start of google drive app you give you some error notification. After that you should have the error message. On click on this I've got nothing, but since you close it and clock on the gDrive - you'll see a grey folder icon and at the bottom a link that say find/specify google drive folder. This is the think you need.

Comment: the answers do not appear in the same order every time. Can you write out the entire process from beginning to end as a complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

New [Backup & Sync app](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) has this ability where you can specify your *Folder location* and choose which folders you want to sync.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS:

1.Open the status-bar menu and click on the gear icon on the top-right corner, then select preferences.

2.in the opened window, select the gear icon. you will see the 'Google Drive folder location' option.

[image]