# Missing permissions for syncing folders on partition with Google Drive for Desktop (macOS 12.1+)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, google-apps

I currently have folders in a partitioned volume that I would like to sync with Google Drive (without moving them to my startup volume). With the Drive for Desktop app, I can choose folders on my startup disk to sync just fine, but trying to choose anything on the partition (i.e. under /Volumes/) gives the error `Can’t sync /Volumes/<...> due to missing folder permission`. What permissions do I need to grant the folder/Drive to be able to do this?

I also tried following the answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247114/can-i-move-the-google-drive-folder-to-a-different-volume) to move my entire Google Drive folder to the partition, but with Apple's introduction of File Provider in macOS 12.1, the location of the Google Drive folder is now [specified by macOS](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/12178485?hl=en) and can't be changed.